# Tablix Filter for Including NULL in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have an **SSRS report**. It has a Marks dropdown, and a resultset "**Classresult**". When I select any value from Marks dropdown, it filters my result for selected value and displays the result.

Say when I select "100" from marks dropdown, it filters my **Classresult** dataset and shows all results with 100 value.

But it doesnot show values which have **NULL** in marks field.(the resultset ClassResult contains NULL values.

Is there any way i can include **NULL** values ??

**Currently my condition is:**

```
Marks == Parameters!Marks.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the ability to wrap an IsNull() around the Class result field in your datasource?
Like IsNull(ClassResult,0) AS Classresult

This will replace nulls with a zero.  Alternately you could replace the 0 with a different value of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `IsNothing()` function to check for a NULL value in an SSRS expression. It returns `TRUE` if the value is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You can include NULL in the query that populates the Marks drop down.  (If you put the available values in statically, then add it there...)  but here is how you can do it in the query.

```
SELECT ValueField, LabelField
FROM MarksTable
UNION 
SELECT '(NULL)', '--NULL--'
```

Then in the query whose results you are filtering add

```
ISNULL([Marks], '(NULL)') as Marks
```